# CSS and website layout

Tags: html, css

Is anybody able to help me replicate the layout of the screen at http://login.microsoftonline.com

What I am after is just two columns, that span the size of the page, so there is no scroll bar or anything.

I want the smaller of the two columns to be on the left, not the right and I want to be able to choose the image for the larger area in the CSS or HTML.

There doesn't need to be any wording, just the two columns, and the larger one with a background image.

Any assistance is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="colmask leftmenu">
    <div class="colleft">
        <div class="col1">
            <!-- Column 1 start -->
            <h2>Right</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <!-- Column 2 start -->
            <h2>Left</h2>
            <!-- Column 2 end -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;           /* This removes the border around the viewport in old versions of IE */
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    min-width:600px;        /* Minimum width of layout - remove line if not required */
                    /* The min-width property does not work in old versions of Internet Explorer */
    font-size:90%;
}
a {
    color:#369;
}
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#369;
    text-decoration:none;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
    padding:0;
}

/* 'widths' sub menu */
#layoutdims {
    clear:both;
    background:#eee;
    border-top:4px solid #000;
    margin:0;
    padding:6px 15px !important;
    text-align:right;
}
/* column container */
.colmask {
    position:relative;  /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;         /* width of whole page */
    overflow:hidden;        /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}
/* common column settings */
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/* 2 Column (left menu) settings */
.leftmenu {
    background:#fff;        /* right column background colour */
}
.leftmenu .colleft {
    right:75%;          /* right column width */
    background:#f4f4f4; /* left column background colour */
}
.leftmenu .col1 {
    width:71%;          /* right column content width */
    left:102%;          /* 100% plus left column left padding */
}
.leftmenu .col2 {
    width:21%;          /* left column content width (column width minus left and right padding) */
    left:6%;            /* (right column left and right padding) plus (left column left padding) */
}
```

I managed to get two columns, but I can't figure out how to make them a single screen (full browser size) and to get an image in the background of 'RIGHT'

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code to see what have you tried so far

Comment: We're not going to write your code. We can point you in the right direction though, if you show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: As far as "any assistance" goes - if you already know a webpage doing what you're trying to do, you can use your favorite browser's development tools (usually hotkeyed on F12) to inspect the CSS of the elements you wonder about.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the code.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the height using height:100vh;

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;           /* This removes the border around the viewport in old versions of IE */
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    min-width:600px;        /* Minimum width of layout - remove line if not required */
                    /* The min-width property does not work in old versions of Internet Explorer */
    font-size:90%;
}
a {
    color:#369;
}
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#369;
    text-decoration:none;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
    padding:0;
}

/* 'widths' sub menu */
#layoutdims {
    clear:both;
    background:#eee;
    border-top:4px solid #000;
    margin:0;
    padding:6px 15px !important;
    text-align:right;
}
/* column container */
.colmask {
    position:relative;  /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;         /* width of whole page */
    overflow:hidden;        /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}
/* common column settings */
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/* 2 Column (left menu) settings */
.leftmenu {
    background:#fff;        /* right column background colour */
}
.leftmenu .colleft {
    right:75%;          /* right column width */
    background:#f4f4f4; /* left column background colour */
}
.leftmenu .col1 {
    width:71%;          /* right column content width */
    left:102%;          /* 100% plus left column left padding */
}
.leftmenu .col2 {
    width:21%;          /* left column content width (column width minus left and right padding) */
    left:6%;            /* (right column left and right padding) plus (left column left padding) */
}
.col1 {
  background-image: url("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png");
}
h2 {
  height: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="colmask leftmenu">
    <div class="colleft">
        <div class="col1">
            <!-- Column 1 start -->
            <h2>Right</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <!-- Column 2 start -->
            <h2>Left</h2>
            <!-- Column 2 end -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```